# How to stop the execution of a function on click

Tags: javascript, concurrency, concurrentmodification

I have this typewriter effect, I also have a website in 3 languages. When changing the language, I want the script to be re-executed with the new language. For this, I added an onclick event. Everything works, but there is a bug, if we change the language during the execution of the script, the new one will be executed on top of the old one. So, how, in my case, can I stop the old script and execute the new one?

I tried to use `return` as posted in other answers, tried to use `clearTimeout` but still doesn't work.

The snippet does not work. I am using localStorage and here it looks like it is locked.

UPD. The snippet is already working.

```js
var isTag, text, langText, i = 0;
  langText = "Hi!<br>Text,<br>Text ";
(function e() {
  if ((text = langText.slice(0, ++i)) !== langText) {
    document.querySelector(".index-title-main h1").innerHTML = text;
    var t = text.slice(-1);
    if ("<" === t && (isTag = !0), ">" === t && (isTag = !1), isTag) return e();
    setTimeout(e, 100);
  }
}());
document.querySelector('.en').onclick = function() {
  var isTag, text, langText, i = 0;
    langText = "Hi!<br>Text,<br>Text ";
  (function e() {
    if ((text = langText.slice(0, ++i)) !== langText) {
      document.querySelector(".index-title-main h1").innerHTML = text;
      var t = text.slice(-1);
      if ("<" === t && (isTag = !0), ">" === t && (isTag = !1), isTag) return e();
      setTimeout(e, 100);
    }
  }());
};
document.querySelector('.de').onclick = function() {
  var isTag, text, langText, i = 0;
    langText = "Hallo!<br>Text,<br>Text ";
  (function e() {
    if ((text = langText.slice(0, ++i)) !== langText) {
      document.querySelector(".index-title-main h1").innerHTML = text;
      var t = text.slice(-1);
      if ("<" === t && (isTag = !0), ">" === t && (isTag = !1), isTag) return e();
      setTimeout(e, 100);
    }
  }());
};
document.querySelector('.ru').onclick = function() {
  var isTag, text, langText, i = 0;
    langText = "Привет!<br>Текст,<br>Текст ";
  (function e() {
    if ((text = langText.slice(0, ++i)) !== langText) {
      document.querySelector(".index-title-main h1").innerHTML = text;
      var t = text.slice(-1);
      if ("<" === t && (isTag = !0), ">" === t && (isTag = !1), isTag) return e();
      setTimeout(e, 100);
    }
  }());
};
```

```css
.lang{
  display: flex;
}
.lang a{
  color: #000;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  transition: .5s;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.lang a:not(:last-child){
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.lang a:hover{
  color: #fff;
  transition: .5s;
  background-color: #000;
}
.index-title-main{
  padding-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="lang">
  <a class="en" href="#">English</a>
  <a class="de" href="#">Deutsche</a>
  <a class="ru" href="#">Русский</a>
</div>
<div class="index-title-main">
  <h1></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a version without localStorage

Comment: Thank! And I made it possible to change the language on click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have refactored your code and moved the common function outside the click event handler.

We need to clear the interval at the start of the function as we can be sure that as the execution has reached here we no longer need any previous running instance of other language click handlers.

```js
var langText, i = 0, timeout;

langText = "Hi!<br>Text,<br>Text ";

function animateText() {
  var isTag, text;
  timeout && clearTimeout(timeout);
  if ((text = langText.slice(0, ++i)) !== langText) {
    document.querySelector(".index-title-main h1").innerHTML = text;
    var t = text.slice(-1);
    if ("<" === t && (isTag = !0), ">" === t && (isTag = !1), isTag) return animateText();
    timeout = setTimeout(animateText, 100);
  }
};

animateText();

document.querySelector('.en').onclick = function() {
  i = 0, langText = "Hi!<br>Text,<br>Text ";
  animateText();
};

document.querySelector('.de').onclick = function() {
  i = 0, langText = "Hallo!<br>Text,<br>Text ";
  animateText();
};

document.querySelector('.ru').onclick = function() {
  i = 0, langText = "Привет!<br>Текст,<br>Текст ";
  animateText();
};
```

```css
.lang{
  display: flex;
}
.lang a{
  color: #000;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  transition: .5s;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.lang a:not(:last-child){
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.lang a:hover{
  color: #fff;
  transition: .5s;
  background-color: #000;
}
.index-title-main{
  padding-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="lang">
  <a class="en" href="#">English</a>
  <a class="de" href="#">Deutsche</a>
  <a class="ru" href="#">Русский</a>
</div>
<div class="index-title-main">
  <h1></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: `document.querySelector(".lang").addEventListener("click",function(e) { const tgt = e.target; if (tgt.classList.contains("en")) ...` or something cleverer with `["en","ru","de"]`

Comment: Ya, except for the language text, everything remains the same. We could add something like you have suggested and then in future if any new lang needs to be added, it would be a smaller change.

Comment: @mplungjan, I take the value of the current language from `localStorage`
or `window.navigator.userLanguage` or `window.navigator.language`, snippet does not allow working with it, so I simplified the example. In the history of the change question, there is an initial example. Btw, is it possible to improve it?

Comment: Yes, very. You are repeating everything over and over. That is highly inefficient

Answer (score 0):

Here is a DRY version

```js
const langTexts = {
  en: "Hi!<br>Text,<br>Text ",
  de: "Hallo!<br>Text,<br>Text ",
  ru: "Привет!<br>Текст,<br>Текст "
}
let langText = langTexts["en"]; // langText[languageFromLocalStorage || "en"]  
let tId, isTag, cnt = 0;
const h1 = document.querySelector(".index-title-main h1");
const typer = () => {
  if ((text = langText.slice(0, ++cnt)) !== langText) {
    h1.innerHTML = text;
    const t = text.slice(-1);
    if ("<" === t && (isTag = !0), ">" === t && (isTag = !1), isTag) return typer();
    tId = setTimeout(typer, 100);
  }
}

document.getElementById("nav").addEventListener("click", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const tgt = e.target;
  console.log(tgt.getAttribute("lang"))
  cnt = 0;
  langText = langTexts[tgt.getAttribute("lang")];
  clearTimeout(tId)
  tId = setTimeout(typer, 100);
})
typer()
```

```css
.lang {
  display: flex;
}

.lang a {
  color: #000;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  transition: .5s;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.lang a:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.lang a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  transition: .5s;
  background-color: #000;
}

.index-title-main {
  padding-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <a class="langLink" href="#" lang="en">English</a>
  <a class="langLink" href="#" lang="de">Deutsch</a>
  <a class="langLink" href="#" lang="ru">Русский</a>
</div>
<div class="index-title-main">
  <h1></h1>
</div>
```